# MySQL UNION - Remove duplicate entries the nice way

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates, union

I use this sql code to combine two search results. One with AND the other one is an OR search.

There are certain results that could be the same of course.. as in this case its the post_id 1186. So it shows up 2x in the result.

Is there any nice way to get rid of the duplicate. I saw some solutions to wrap it in another SELECT but this will throw an error because of duplicate entries. Maybe there is a better way you know of?

```
SELECT pt.post_text, pt.bbcode_uid, pt.post_subject, p.*, f.forum_id, f.forum_name, t.*, u.username, u.user_id, u.user_sig, u.user_sig_bbcode_uid, 1 sortby  
            FROM phpbb_forums f, phpbb_topics t, phpbb_users u, phpbb_posts p, phpbb_posts_text pt 
            WHERE p.post_id IN (1186)
                AND pt.post_id = p.post_id
                AND f.forum_id = p.forum_id
                AND p.topic_id = t.topic_id
                AND t.topic_id <> 3765
                AND p.poster_id = u.user_id

                GROUP BY t.topic_id
                UNION
                SELECT pt.post_text, pt.bbcode_uid, pt.post_subject, p.*, f.forum_id, f.forum_name, t.*, u.username, u.user_id, u.user_sig, u.user_sig_bbcode_uid, 2 sortby  
            FROM phpbb_forums f, phpbb_topics t, phpbb_users u, phpbb_posts p, phpbb_posts_text pt 
            WHERE p.post_id IN (8885, 12013, 1186, 4362, 4451, 4059, 8957, 10121, 11553, 11554, 12130, 12201, 4573, 4543, 4721, 5142, 5157, 5557, 5736, 5745, 5783, 5862, 6058, 6076, 6077, 6153, 6180, 6191, 6236, 6357, 6358, 6495, 6586, 6670, 4856, 6745, 6872, 7009, 7052, 7094, 7106, 7164, 7194, 4625, 4585, 4242, 4589, 4014, 4450, 4454, 4015, 4841, 7416, 7447, 7552, 4017, 4427, 7938, 8002, 8201, 8241, 8306, 8371, 8429, 8474, 8494, 8546, 8713, 8771, 8804, 9031, 9065, 9140, 9178, 9249, 9385, 9466, 9892, 10016, 10308, 10495, 10636, 10753, 10815, 10859, 11485, 11688, 11767, 11830, 12155, 12250)
                AND pt.post_id = p.post_id
                AND f.forum_id = p.forum_id
                AND p.topic_id = t.topic_id
                AND t.topic_id <> 3765
                AND p.poster_id = u.user_id

                GROUP BY t.topic_id ORDER BY sortby, rankscore DESC LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Comment: If you are using UNION you shouldn't have aby duplicates, you still have some?

Comment: Group By without any aggregate functions is unlikely to yield the result you want.

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz Yes I still have. I guess it could be due to the extra "sortby" added to the SELECT to have the first Result favored and than the second union afterwards... Dunno

Comment: @P.Salmon what do you mean by that?

Comment: group by will group multiple rows and return a single row expecting an aggregate function...

Comment: using union here will still bring duplicate pt.post_id as the last column sort by makes the whole row unique and thus union does not consider it as a repeated row.. hence using distinct might only be the way out

Comment: To my knowledge UNION is enough to get rid of duplicates, GROUP BY gets rid of them.

Comment: Wait, you have that column sortby, it always distincts even the same rows in your datasets.

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz Yes the "sortby" is used to favor the first result and show it before the other one.

Comment: Usinng group by in this way is unsafe in my view you should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html and rethink your query.

Comment: Why not just remove the 1186 from the second unioned select ?

Comment: @LukStorms Maybe I have to do that in PHP than. Somehow thought I missed something in SQL but maybe it's a logic flaw in itself I got there ;)

Comment: @Spiele-Umsonst, I agree with  LukStorms, why can't you remove it?

Comment: I can remove it I guess. Both "IN"-Lists are "strings" in PHP. I can compare them and delete duplicate ones. Never did that but it should be possible. I just thought I could solve this problem with MySQL in the first run...